# Syntax error in for line in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am running a python script. I am getting an unexplained syntax error in `for` line.
This is the code:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
url="http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid?"
print "INSERT INTO Property (URL,Rooms, Place, Phonenumber1,Phonenumber2,Phonenumber3,Typeofperson, Name)"
print "VALUES ("

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    properties = soup.findAll(('a', {'title':re.compile('Bedroom')}),('i',{'class':'pdate'})
    for eachproperty in properties:
     print today,","+ "http:/" + eachproperty['href'] ",", eachproperty.string"," ,.join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", eachproperty['onclick'])) 
     print ")"
```

Error is

```
$ python properties.py
  File "properties.py", line 15
    for eachproperty in properties:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Update**

Is the following line correct ?

```
properties = soup.findAll(('a', {'title':re.compile('Bedroom')}),('i',{'class':'pdate'}))
```

Comment: Count the number of `)` and `(` on the previous line.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I have updated the question with one more doubt. Because, there is no error displayed. but no output too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *preceding* line has an incorrect count of opening `(` parenthesis compared to the number of closing parens:

```
properties = soup.findAll(('a', {'title':re.compile('Bedroom')}),('i',{'class':'pdate'})
#                      --^^                     ---^      ---^-^-^                -----^
```

Add one more closing `)`:

```
properties = soup.findAll(('a', {'title':re.compile('Bedroom')}),('i',{'class':'pdate'}))
```